# SSIS Package Error "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only." for Excel Destination

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

When I execute a package in Visual Studio it works fine. However, when executing that package in SQL I run into this error  "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only." and the Subcomponent name for this error message, is Excel Destination.

I tried adding "IMEX=0;Readonly=False", to the connection string of Excel Connection Manager but didn't help

I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654325/12021687 and I know my database is read-only (which I can't change) but I don't believe it relevant to me as the Subcomponent name of the error message is Excel Destination.

Can someone guide me on what may be causing this issue?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Permission Issue. Package may not be running under the user you are expecting.

- Try changing the security permissions of the file/folder to full control for NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT.

Rerun the package. If this works check who the file was last saved by and give this user the required permissions.

p.s. Very Frustrating issue for myself too!

*Edit*
Also before I found the above as soloution:

1. I set DelayValidation = True everywhere in the Project.
2. Added ;READONLY=0 on the connection string